# Integral with bounds

Tags: definite-integrals

I have define integral:

$$\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin x\,dx}{1+\cos^2x}=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin x\,dx}{1+\cos^2x}$$

my question is how do we get that $\pi/2$

Comment: Yeah that right,thanks for editing

Comment: You have not checked any of answers to your questions, even they provide full details

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. One may use
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx
$$ with
$$
a=0,\quad b=\pi, \quad f(x)=\frac{x \sin x}{1+\cos^2x}.
$$

Comment: @user5927353 One may observe that $f(\pi-x)=\frac{(\pi-x) \sin x}{1+\cos^2x}$, since $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$ and $\cos^2(\pi-x)=\cos^2 x$.

Answer (score 4):

Write:
$$I=\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin x\,dx}{1+\cos^2x},$$
$$I=\int_0^\pi (x-\frac{\pi}{2})\frac{\sin x\,dx}{1+\cos^2x}+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin x\,dx}{1+\cos^2x},$$
$$I=I_1+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin x\,dx}{1+\cos^2x}.$$
Now
$$I_1\stackrel{\text{substitute: }x\to (x-\frac{\pi}{2})}=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x\cos{x}}{1+\sin^2{x}} dx=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(x)=0,$$ where in the last step we used the fact that $f(x)$ is odd.

Finally, $$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin x\,dx}{1+\cos^2x}.$$